# Java: How to wait for the listener to execute the next line?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a problem because I have the next code in my main class:

```
SelectCalculatorWindow selectCalculatorWindow = new SelectCalculatorWindow();
CalcWindow calcWindow;

if (selectCalculatorWindow.getOption() == SelectCalculatorWindow.BASIC_OPTION) {
    calcWindow = new CalcWindow(0);
} else if (selectCalculatorWindow.getOption() == SelectCalculatorWindow.PSEUDOSCIENTIFIC_OPTION) {
    calcWindow = new CalcWindow(1);
}
```

And, in other class (SelectCalculatorWindow), I have this:

```
public SelectCalculatorWindow() {
    initComponents();
    instantiateListener();
}

private void instantiateListener() {
    acceptBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(basicCalculatorRbtn.isSelected()) {
                setOption(BASIC_OPTION);
            } else if (pseudoscientificCalculatorRbtn.isSelected()) {
                setOption(PSEUDOSCIENTIFIC_OPTION);
            }
            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

So, I want that condition sentences that I wrote in the main class execute only if user click the button, and I don't know how to do it

Comment: Please ask if anything in my answer is confusing or doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted a valid [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) program yet, and so I can only guess, but having said that, my guess is that `SelectCalculatorWindow` creates and displays a JFrame which is a non-modal application window, which is not what you want. Instead you will want to display a *modal* child-window, or dialog, such as a modal JDialog. When you use this, it pauses application code flow in the calling code until the dialog has been dealt with, and so allows your program to pause waiting for the user to make their selection, and then resume the code once the selection has been made.

A JOptionPane is an example of a type of modal dialog, but using a JDialog, you can create windows as varied and flexible as a JFrame, but with the advantages noted above.